# How to run one test method only in selenium grid

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-grid, surefire

I'm using JUnit 4.8.1 and Surefire 2.8.1. In my machine I can run one test method only by doing:

`$$ mvn clean test -Dtest=TestClass#TestMethod`

But when running the same command in the grid configuration, all tests from TestClass are run.

The only difference in the pom is the

```
<configuration>
   <parallel>both</parallel>
</configuration>
```

configuration in the surefire-plugin.

Any idea, how do I run only one test method in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

possible solution is to use `@Categories` annotation. But I use simple web driver(not grid).
try step by step set up [here](http://johndobie.blogspot.com/2012/04/unit-and-integration-tests-with-maven.html)

The idea is in following:
you annotate a set of tests you want to exclude and then you show in POM file that you exclude'em in a way somthing like that:

```
<configuration>
<excludes>
<exclude>blablabla.class</exclude>
</excludes>
</configuration>
```

Hope this somehow helps you.

Comment: This is different from what I want. The idea is not to exclude a given class: is to select the individual @Test methods in a class to be executed.
This is easily done locally, but in grid, it doesn't work.